# How to print the csv file excluding first column till end using awk

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file with dynamic columns.
I've tried to use `awk -F , 'NF>1' resul1.txt` but it still prints all columns.

Since it has dynamic columns.
Its quite difficult to print using print `$1` till end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk command:

```
awk -F, '{$1=""}1' input.txt | awk -vOFS=, '{$1=$1}1' > output.txt
```

- Make the 1st field empty
- Print out entire line again

Answer (score 0):

try ***substr*** function :

> **substr(string, start [, length ])**
>       Return a length-character-long substring of string, starting at character number start. The first character of a string is character
>   number one.For example, substr("washington", 5, 3) returns "ing".*

```
awk -F, '{print substr($0,length($1)+1+length(FS))}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -d',' -f2- yourfile.csv > output.csv
```

**Explanation**:

- `-d` - setting delimiter to `,`
- `-f` - fields to print
- `2-` - from `2` field to end of line

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{sub(/[^,]+,/,"",$0);}1' OFS=, yourfile.csv > output.csv
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^,]\+,//g' yourfile.csv
```

- `-i` - in-place edit